# what's the difference between worklignt 6.2 and mobile first 7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have been using `mobilefirst 7.0` and now I now have to sit for an exam about `worklight 6.2`.

What differences should I take into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

One of the bigger changes in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 is the introduction of OAuth and Java adapters. However you can find out much more in the release notes: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_release_notes.html

Also note that you should go through the release notes of the previous version to 7.0, which is MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_release_notes.html